# AG Grid react change master detail content dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ag-grid, master-detail

I am having an issue with AG Grid React, I have a system where we have a master detail containing another nested AG Grid inside it, that inside Grid also contains another nested Grid inside a different master detail, on top of that we have a select in which when the option changes from 'summary' to 'detailed' the inner grid either hide or display its master detail
This last step is the problem, where the grid is not refreshing in a way that allows the inside grid to change
I will provide some screenshots and steps to demonstrate
[image: Step 1, Summary View]
[image: Step 2, Summary view expanded]
Inside the inner grid near the "Customer 1" is where the inside grid would be
[image: Step 3]
I can only reach the 3rd stage when i manually change the state in the code from "summary" to "detailed", however when the state changes by selection nothing happens
here is a snapshot of the code (I only included relevant parts)

State used:

`

```
const [isSummary, setIsSummary] = useState(false)
```

`

columns for the inner table:
`

```
            field: "accountNumber",
            headerName: "Account No",
            cellRenderer: currentElement === 3 ? 'agGroupCellRenderer' : isSummary ? null : 'agGroupCellRenderer',
```

`Cell renderes (detailCellRenderer is the table that "hides" and "shows" depending on the selected input, the detailCellRenderer2 is the value that never changes though I need it to change)`

```
    const detailCellRenderer = ({ data }) => {
        return (
            <div className="py-4">
                <AgGrid
                    data={data?.invoices}
                    columns={columns}
                    pagination={false}
                    autoHight={true}
                    autoSize={true}
                    forPrinting={true}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    const detailCellRenderer2 = ({ data }) => {
        return (
            <div className="py-4">
                <AgGrid
                    data={data?.customers}
                    columns={cust_columns}
                    pagination={false}
                    autoHight={true}
                    autoSize={true}
                    forPrinting={true}
                    masterDetail={currentElement === 3 ? true : !isSummary}
                    detailCellRenderer={currentElement === 3 ? detailCellRenderer : !isSummary ? detailCellRenderer : null}
                    subTable={currentElement === 3 ? columns : !isSummary ? columns : null}
                    subTableObj={currentElement === 3 ? "invoices" : !isSummary ? "invoices" : null}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

`The Grid:`

```
                                            <AgGrid
                                                        data={reportData?.groups}
                                                        columns={hubs_columns}
                                                        pagination={false}
                                                        forPrinting={true}
                                                        autoHight={true}
                                                        autoSize={true}
                                                        exportToExcel={exportToExcelClicked}
                                                        setExportToExcelClicked={setExportToExcelClicked}
                                                        setDisabledExportBtn={setDisabledExportBtn}
                                                        setIsLoadingGridExport={setIsLoadingGridExport}
                                                        masterDetail={true}
                                                        detailCellRenderer={detailCellRenderer2}
                                                        subTable={cust_columns}
                                                        subTableObj={"customers"}
                                                        fileName={fileName}
                                                    />
```

`

Several attempts where made, at first regarding the grid component it self, I added the function
`

```
gridRef?.current?.api?.redrawRows();
```

`
every time the state changes, I tried to empty and then rerender the state data, I tried to generate different cell renderers and put them as functions which are used inside the AG Grid component instead of passing them as props...finally I tried to see if anything happens when the input changes, and I discovered that CellRenderer2 which is the cell renderer that includes the table that needs changing never changes as the state changes, it always stays "static"
If anyone have done this or something similar I would appreciate any help